# Datattable sort function issue

Tags: jquery, datatable

My datatable has lost the ability to toggle by 'asc' and 'desc' on click. It works fine when I get rid of the table header click functions but when they are added like in the provided example the ability to toggle between 'asc' and 'desc' is lost. My code seems to be interfering with the default datatable code any answers or suggestions?

**Issues**

I cannot get the table heading to to toggle between 'asc' and 'dec' and if it does work other parts of the functionality such as search cease to function properly.

**Overview**

I have a table that is searching by individual columns. You can select which column is searched in one of two ways.

1. There is a dropdown that lists all the column names and when you select the option the corresponding table header sorts to 'asc' then if you click the table heading you can toggle between 'asc' and 'desc'.
2. You can also simply click on the table heading and the corresponding select option will be selected. The table heading will also always start off as 'asc' and you will have the ability to toggle between 'asc' and 'desc' on click.

**Code**

**[JSFiddle - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mu7t4e4y/14/)**

```
$('#dtSelect').change(function () {
    var searchInput = $("#searchInput");

    if ($(this).val() == "0") {

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(1):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(1):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });
    }

        else if ($(this).val() == "1") {

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(2):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(2):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });
    }

        else if ($(this).val() == "2") {

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(3):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(3):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });
    }

        else if ($(this).val() == "3") {

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(4):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(4):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });
    }

        else if ($(this).val() == "4") {

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });
    }

        else if ($(this).val() == "5") {

        $("#searchBtn").on('click', function () {
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(6):not(:contains('" + searchInput.val() + "'))").parent("tr").css("display", "none");
            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(6):contains('" + searchInput.val() + "')").parent("tr").css("display", "");
        });
    }

});

$('#dtSelect').change(function () {
    var column = $(this).val();
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    if (column !== "") {
        oTable.fnSort([
            [column, 'asc']
        ]);
    }
});

$('th:nth-child(1):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(0).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(2):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(1).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(3):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(2).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(4):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(3).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(5):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(4).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(6):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(5).change();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because you are linking `column header click` and `selecting in the drop down`.

On clicking on one of the headers - let's say `Office` - it triggers `$('#dtSelect').change(function ()` and sets the sort order to `['Office', 'asc']`

Change the following line:

```
if (column !== "") {
```

to

```
 if (column !== "" && event.currentTarget === this) {
```

That will trigger the `oTable.fnSort([[column, 'asc']]);` only when the drop down value is changed, and not when the column header is clicked.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/_prakash/mu7t4e4y/19/

Comment: This seems to be working I will just test it in my actual code to be sure. Just a heads up your jsfiddle is not working I just added the suggested change my self.

Comment: It works perfectly. If you have a chance could you explain the cod a bit just so I can understand the next time I encounter this something like this.

Comment: Awesome. See http://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/ for what `event.currentTarget` means. Essentially, by adding the `event.currentTarget === this` condition within the `$('#dtSelect').change` block, I am saying that the next step can happen only if it was called on changing the drop down value. And not when the same event is triggered from other event - like clicking the column header.